# How to avoid pandas creating an index in a saved csv

Tags: python, csv, indexing, pandas

I am trying to save a csv to a folder after making some edits to the file.

Every time I use `pd.to_csv('C:/Path of file.csv')` the csv file has a separate column of indexes. I want to avoid printing the index to csv.

I tried:

```
pd.read_csv('C:/Path to file to edit.csv', index_col = False)
```

And to save the file...

```
pd.to_csv('C:/Path to save edited file.csv', index_col = False)
```

However, I still got the unwanted index column. How can I avoid this when I save my files?

Comment: Can we use this in ms excel as well?

Comment: Yes you can `pd.to_excel(r'file.xlsx', index = False)`

Comment: `index_col` works for `read_html()` as well.

Answer (score 1120):

Use `index=False`.

```
df.to_csv('your.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 136):

There are two ways to handle the situation where we do not want the index to be stored in csv file.

1. As others have stated you can use ***index=False*** while saving your
   dataframe to csv file.

   > `df.to_csv('file_name.csv',index=False)`
2. Or you can save your dataframe as it is with an index, and while reading you just drop the column **unnamed 0** containing your previous index.Simple!

   > `df.to_csv(' file_name.csv ')`
   >   `df_new = pd.read_csv('file_name.csv').drop(['unnamed 0'],axis=1)`

Comment: "and while reading you just drop the column unnamed 0 containing your previous index" a better way do to this is specify `pd.read_csv(..., index_col=[0]`, and avoid the extra "drop" call.

Answer (score 116):

If you want no index, read file using:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', index_col=0)
```

save it using

```
df.to_csv('file.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: I cant believe nobody noticed the error. To save to csv, it would be `df.to_csv('file.csv', index=False)`

Answer (score 34):

As others have stated, if you don't want to save the index column in the first place, you can use `df.to_csv('processed.csv', index=False)`

However, since the data you will usually use, have some sort of index themselves, let's say a 'timestamp' column, I would keep the index and load the data using it.

So, to save the indexed data, first set their index and then save the DataFrame:

```
df.set_index('timestamp')
df.to_csv('processed.csv')
```

Afterwards, you can either read the data with the index:

```
pd.read_csv('processed.csv', index_col='timestamp')
```

or read the data, and then set the index:

```
pd.read_csv('filename.csv')
pd.set_index('column_name')
```

Comment: If I set the index_col then saved, I still had a numerical unnamed column in the csv. (Python2)

Answer (score 20):

Another solution if you want to keep this column as index.

```
pd.read_csv('filename.csv', index_col='Unnamed: 0')
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you. That somehow helps to translate the concept of primary key transparently, even when using csv

Comment: Very good idea!!! I tried it, and it's very elegant solution!!!

Answer (score 19):

If you want a good format next statement is the best:

```
dataframe_prediction.to_csv('filename.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

In this case you have got a csv file with ',' as separate between columns and utf-8 format.
In addition, numerical index won't appear.