# python hdfs writer adds an extra index column to output csv

Tags: python, hdfs

I need to write a csv to hdfs. Currently i am using hdfs module for doing that.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['FirstName','LastName','City'])
d = InsecureClient('http://localhost:50070')
with d.write(path, encoding = 'utf-8', overwrite=True) as writer:
    df.to_csv(writer)
```

file is succesfully generated, but it adds and extra index column as starting to the csv. I need to have the file with the columns i have specified. how i can remove this index? i could not find any parameter for that.

```
#current output:
,"FirstName","LastName","City"
0,"John","Doo","New York" 
1,"Jane","Doo","San Francisco"

#expected:
"FirstName","LastName","City"
"John","Doo","New York"
"Jane","Doo","San Francisco"
```

thanks in advance,
clairvoyant

update: using pandas package to create my csv

Comment: Change `df.to_csv(writer)` to `df.to_csv(writer, index=False)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid Python/Pandas creating an index in a saved csv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20845213/how-to-avoid-python-pandas-creating-an-index-in-a-saved-csv)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `index=False` when calling `to_csv` (it defaults to `True`).