# copying dictionary data to csv using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

When I print `temp_dict` , it is something like this,

```
 {u'part_b_deductible': None, u'off_exchange': True, u'plan_description': None, u'sbc_download_url': None, u'price_note': None, u'starting_percentage_fpl': 0.0, u'is_uhc_plan': False, 'issuer_id': (484,), u'promotional_label': None, u'metal_level_name': u'Silver', u'network_url': None, u'group_or_individual_plan_type': u'Group', u'treatment_cost_calculator_url': None, u'hios_plan_identifier': u'99806CAAUSJ-TMP', u'original_medicare': None, u'part_d_prescription_coverage': None, u'data_sourced_from': u'uhc', u'price_period': u'Monthly', u'is_age_29_plan': False, u'type': u'MetalPlan', u'plan_year': 2018.0, u'plan_detail_footer': None, u'default_bhp': None, u'formulary_url': None, u'plan_detail_items': None, u'highlight_6': None, u'highlight_4': None, u'highlight_5': None, u'hsa_eligible': 0.0, u'highlight_3': u'PCP 20% coinsurance', u'highlight_1': u'Silver', u'name': u'WI 80 INDEMNITY 18 OPTION 1 SILVER RX $10/45/90/25%', u'network_description': None, u'plan_detail_header': None, 'service_area_id': (1,), u'ending_percentage_fpl': 0.0, u'highlight_2': u'Indemnity', u'on_exchange': False, u'network_type': u'Indemnity', u'recommended': None}
```

But when I copy it in the csv, the data there is -

```
,data_sourced_from,default_bhp,ending_percentage_fpl,formulary_url,group_or_individual_plan_type,highlight_1,highlight_2,highlight_3,highlight_4,highlight_5,highlight_6,hios_plan_identifier,hsa_eligible,is_age_29_plan,is_uhc_plan,issuer_id,metal_level_name,name,network_description,network_type,network_url,off_exchange,on_exchange,original_medicare,part_b_deductible,part_d_prescription_coverage,plan_description,plan_detail_footer,plan_detail_header,plan_detail_items,plan_year,price_note,price_period,promotional_label,recommended,sbc_download_url,service_area_id,starting_percentage_fpl,treatment_cost_calculator_url,type
0,uhc,,0.0,,Group,Silver,Indemnity,PCP 20% coinsurance,,,,99806CAAUSJ-TMP6,0.0,False,False,484,Silver,WI 80 INDEMNITY 18 OPTION 1 SILVER RX $10/45/90/25%,,Indemnity,,True,False,,,,,,,,2018.0,,Monthly,,,,1,0.0,,MetalPlan
```

using below code:

```
  (pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data=temp_dict, orient='columns')
                             .to_csv('dump.csv', header=True))
```

Why is it starting with a comma ??

Edit -:

Not sure why the downvote to the question. Can this be upvoted pls.

Comment: you forgot to pass the argument `index=False` to your csv function. This is a common mistake when you don't care about a numbered index (0,1,2,...). But let us say you had datetime as index, then you would want that to come with. It's a trade-off.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid Python/Pandas creating an index in a saved csv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20845213/how-to-avoid-python-pandas-creating-an-index-in-a-saved-csv)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use parameter `index=False`:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data=temp_dict, orient='columns')
            .to_csv('dump.csv', header=True, index=False)
```

If want only header:

```
pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns.tolist()).to_csv('dump.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: If I have to write only the headers . Can I do that ??

Comment: It is not giving me the headers

Comment: @user1896796 - tested and added solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(temp_dict)
df.to_csv('dump.csv', sep=',', index=None)
```

Comment: If I have to write only the headers . Can I do that ??