# Pandas: printing to csv also creates an unlabelled column with row indices

Tags: pandas, csv

I use the following code to print  a dataframe into a csv file based on the answers seen at this question:
[How to avoid Python/Pandas creating an index in a saved csv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20845213/how-to-avoid-python-pandas-creating-an-index-in-a-saved-csv)

```
y_insincere = [classify_text(text,trimmed_posterior_dict)<0 for text in X_test]
X_output = pd.DataFrame() 
X_output['number'] = number
X_output['CASE'] = case
X_output.to_csv('submission.csv',header=True,columns = ['id','case'],index='False')
```

However, when I look at the csv file it has an extra column without a header with row indices. I tried other fixes from the above question, but nothing worked. I am stuck. Any help appreciated

Comment: `X_output.to_csv('submission.csv',header=True,columns = ['id','case'],index=False)` `'False'` is not `False` in pandas

Comment: @W-B Oops.That must be the error. Thank you! Wonder why it didn't throw an error.