# python，How to delete the serial number of print？

Tags: python, csv

The print result has a serial number, how do I delete it

```py
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("G:/jeri/1.csv",usecols=['Age'])
print(data)
f = open (r'G:/hello.txt','w')
print (data,file = f)
```

Open the output txt text to get the result

```py
   Age
0   24
1   29
2   32
3   23
4   58
5   42
6   37
7   42
8   51
```

0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,  I'm a beginner， how do I delete it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid Python/Pandas creating an index in a saved csv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20845213/how-to-avoid-python-pandas-creating-an-index-in-a-saved-csv)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the single column, you could also use `to_csv()` to write the file. For example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("1.csv", usecols=['Age'])
df.to_csv("hello.txt", index=False)
```