# PySpark Replace Characters using regex and remove column on Databricks

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I am tring to remove a column and special characters from the dataframe shown below.

The code below used to create the dataframe is as follows:

```
dt = pd.read_csv(StringIO(response.text), delimiter="|", encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

The above produces the following output:

[image]

I need help with regex to remove the characters Ã¯Â»Â¿ and delete the first column.

As regards regex, I have tried the following:

```
dt.withColumn('Ã¯Â»Â¿COUNTRY ID', regexp_replace('Ã¯Â»Â¿COUNTRY ID', @"[^0-9a-zA-Z_]+"_ ""))
```

However, I'm getting a syntax error.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: regexp replace is pyspark function for rows and it looks like you are using it for pandas dataframe for column name replace

Comment: Anjaneya, thanks for reaching out. I see what you mean, I was hoping someone could help with regex for Pandas. Can you still help with Regex for Pandas? If not can you let me know how to get the result with PySpark. I hope I'm making sense

Comment: Alternatively, can you let me know what the alternative is in pyspark for ```dt = pd.read_csv(StringIO(response.text),sep="|", encoding='base64')```

Comment: My guess is ```dt = spark.read.csv(StringIO(response.text),sep="|", encoding='base64')```

Comment: I don't think it will work as read.csv expects a path to be provided but if you want some discussion without cluttering comments we can try [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245568/spark-discussion)

Comment: I think I have probably confused the community with my request in this question. So, I will submit a new question.

Comment: Could you post the output of `response.text`?  and is the response is from requests module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the position of incoming column is fixed you can use regex to remove extra characters from column name like below

```
import re

colname = pdf.columns[0]
colt=re.sub("[^0-9a-zA-Z_\s]+","",colname)
print(colname,colt)
pdf.rename(columns={colname:colt}, inplace = True)
```

And for dropping index column you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20845213/how-to-avoid-python-pandas-creating-an-index-in-a-saved-csv) stack answer

Answer (score 0):

You have read in the data as a pandas dataframe. From what I see, you want a spark dataframe. Convert from pandas to spark and rename columns. That will dropn pandas default index column which in your case you refer to as first column. You then can rename the columns. Code below

```
df=spark.createDataFrame(df).toDF('COUNTRY',' COUNTRY NAME').show()
```